# Can't figure out why tkinter program won't turn entry into variable

Tags: tkinter

I've been trying to turn my tkinter entries into a variable all day and have asked various questions to figure out different aspects of this. I feel that the code I have now should work and when I run it I receive no errors but it won't execute what I want it to, here's what I have:

```
from tkinter import*

top = Tk('Outfit Randomizer')

#gender entry
L1 = Label(top, text = 'What is your gender? Type 1 for male and 2 for female')
L1.gride(row = 0, column = 0)
g = StringVar()
E1 = Entry(top, bd = 5, textvariable = g)
E1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

#submit function
def submit():
    g.get()

#submit button
MyButton1 = Button(top, text = 'Submit', width = 10, command = submit)
MyButton1.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

#carry out function
gender = g.get()
if gender == '1':
    print('cool')

top.mainloop()
```

I'm new to coding but as far as I can tell this should work, I receive no errors but nothing prints when I enter 1 in the window. Please let me know how I can fix this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `submit` function gets the entered value - and does absolutely nothing with it.  Your code that prints "cool" is called only once, before the mainloop is entered, so there's no possibility of a value being entered yet.  You need to move that code inside `submit`.